# Accessing ngModel elements that use a class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have many elements in my HTML code that have their `ngModel` assignment defined as `ng-model = "object.[something]"`.

For example:

`<div class="form-group row" ng-model="object.askUser">`

I do this to be clear of my purpose for these elements. My question is how do I access these element in my Javascript? Do I call `$scope.object.askUser`, `$object.askUser`, or something else? I had a hard time finding things on the web about this, most likely because I wasn't quite sure of the words to use in the search bar to describe what I am trying to do.

Comment: First of all you need to set scope object on the controller then use the scope object on ng-model

Comment: I believe cheralathan is correct. You need to include $scope as a parameter in your controller function, like this. `angular.controller(function($scope){})` Then you can refer to scope variables in the controller such as `$scope.object` or `$scope.object.askUser`.

Comment: I already have `app.controller('controller-name', ['$scope', function($scope) { //blahblah }` at the top of my Javascript and everything is included in that.

Comment: Ah. Another snag I just noticed is that `ng-model` is only applicable to input elements. If you have data on `$scope` that you want displayed one-way to the html view, try `<div>{{object.askUser}}</div>`. Otherwise, to capture input data and manipulate it in the controller scope, try `<input ng-model="object.askUser">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your controller use `$scope.object.askUser`:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
 
  $scope.someObject = {};
  
  $scope.someObject.askUser = "Hello, world!";
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input ng-model="someObject.askUser" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Side note:**

You use in your example `<div>` with `ngModel`.

[ngModel Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

> The ngModel directive binds an **input,select, textarea (or custom form
>   control)** to a property on the scope

If you want to one-way bind a model to a div use [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

```
<div class="form-group row">
   {{ object.askUser }}
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I think the solution to the first problem I was having was the add the `$scope.object = {};` line in my Javascript. What I am trying to do in this case is set the `ngHide` value of a certain element to `true`. I use `ng-click` in the HTML to call a function that does this: `$scope.object.[element-name].ngHide = "true"`, but I get an error that says "Cannot set property 'ngHIde' of undefined".

Comment: So you need to bind `ngHide`. Look in this fiddle for an example [https://jsfiddle.net/g06grpwa/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/g06grpwa/4/) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thanks for the fiddle, that helped me get a clearer picture. I'm just not as comfortable with the MVC model as I should be, and that may be why AngularJS gives me confusion sometimes.

Comment: I see the word "bind" used a lot in AngularJS discussions. Can you clarify for me exactly what that word means in this context?

Comment: Sure :) It basically means syncing between the model and the view. When I said bind `ngHide` I meant sync `ngHide` to some variable in your controller. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look and try to really understand AngularJS as I continue to work with it.